# Database Name Annotation for Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework 2.2

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a standard composer project for Zf2.2 with Doctrine 2.implementing the steps laid out at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/overview.html and installing Doctrine 2 via composer.

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "0.0.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.0"
    }
}
```

As at now the project has only 1 Doctrine connection 'orm_default':

```
return array (
    'doctrine' => array (
        'connection' => array (
            'orm_default' => array (
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver', 
                'params' => array (
                    'host' => 'localhost', 
                    'port' => '3306', 
                    'user' => 'sameuser', 
                    'password' => 'samepassword', 
                    'dbname' => 'dbname1', 
                    'charset' => 'utf8' 
                ) 
            ) 
        ), 
        'driver' => array (
            'modulename_entities' => array (
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver', 
                'cache' => 'array', 
                'paths' => array (
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/Modulename/Entity' 
                ) 
            ), 

            'orm_default' => array (
                'drivers' => array (
                    'Modulename\Entity' => 'modulename_entities' 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

My typical application format separates different business functions into different databases. So, a lot of the application information goes into a "main" database, marketing info into a "mktg" db, and back-end stuff, like errors goes into another.

An extensive Google search brought about the option of adding the dbname to the Entity Annotations like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 * (
 *      name="dbname2.error_tickets",
 *      indexes=
 *      {
 *
...
 *      }
 * )
 *
 */
class Error....
```

However, when I run

```
doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

and get:

```
ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...
Database schema created successfully!
```

Table error_tickets is not created in ANY database. No errors are displayed. Yet, when I annotate like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 * (
 *      name="error_tickets",
 *      indexes=
 *      {
 *
...
 *      }
 * )
 *
 */
class Error....
```

or so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 * (
 *      name="dbname1.error_tickets",
 *      indexes=
 *      {
 *
...
 *      }
 * )
 *
 */
class Error....
```

and run

```
doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

Table error_tickets is created in my default dbname1.

I have read that adding the dbname to the Table annotation is a way to "trick" doctrine into creating said table on another database without going into lengthy, unsupported design hacks that aren't really production ready. I have ensured the following:

- The sameuser has 'ALL PRIVILEGES' to both databases
- Both databases are on the same server
- No other design hack was implemented (I've tried them). This is a clean, working zf2 + D2 install
- setting the 'dbname' key in my doctrine.local.php to any of null, FALSE, '' or not setting it at all, stops any table from being created in any database.

Question: What else is needed for this "trick" to work?

The simplest/most stable solution will be best

Comment: If you use different Databases, you have to use different connection settings. DBName is set inside the Connection as you have noticed. When a set of entities belongs to one DB and another set of entities belongs to another DB, then set up your drivers accordingly for some entities to use one driver and other entities to use another ;) (namespace based usually)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'm not able to find doctrine supported examples for this in zf2.2. I have found a lot of pretty impressive hacks but these all come with a "don't use on production" disclaimer. Any suggested example code?

Comment: OK. I have pretty much given up on trying this "trick". I did find these two links: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/122  and  https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#how-to-use-two-connections. After a little tweaking it works but is limited to One Module to One Database. I'm sure there is a way to get around this - the errors I got during my trials seem promising

Answer (score 0):

two things I can suggest on this situation:

1. Can you validate the schema you created with this [command](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation)? Its always great to validate after you've created the mappings.

   doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
2. Do a reverse engineering like after changing on you database(like making your preferred schema). Use `orm:convert-mapping` ([docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering)) after you change on your schema which will generate the mappings, entities and proxies. You can read more about the console commands of doctrine 2 [here](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm starting the project from scratch so the plan is to start with the basics we've drawn up and prototype as we go along.

Comment: yah, those commands of doctrine2 in cli will help you a lot about schema or entity generation. Any questions you have about reverse engineering with orm:convert-mapping?

Comment: Also, validating the schema works but only on the default database. I'll keep the mapping conversion in mind. Nice feature eventually

Comment: yah,that helped a lot. as you go more into production you will need some columns and then you do generate the entities and mapping by the schema.